# Each 48 items of array write to datagrid

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, string, datagrid

I need help writing some code. When I do this, I have a huge list of data more precisely this is the array of words I need each 48 items of array write to  datagrid

**example**
data 1
data 2
data 3
data 4
....
....
....
....`
data 50

row -------> data 1 data 2  data 3  data 4...data 48 //in data grid 
each 48 items write to new row and each array item in a separate colony
if this item number 49 then he write in next row 
The length of the array is not created
in the original, these data from the CSV file divided the words I could and then alas.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Stack overflow isn't a code writing service so it might be better to attempt to write the code yourself and explain where you are getting stuck. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It is a logical problem. Why you don't just iterate each 48th item with Linq, or the simple foreach loop? How you can archive it, is simple as that: search and learn. And you have to work with the control DataGridView ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx))...

Comment: Yes, I tried to write the code but alas I spent dozens of pages it alas

Comment: I wrote a small piece of code but I do not know how to add it

Comment: string lin = @"C:\Users\someuser\Desktop\New folder (7)\flltest.txt";
        
using (StreamReader fs = new StreamReader(lin,  Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1255")))

Comment: while (true)
                {
                
                    string temp = fs.ReadLine();
                    Char delimiter = ',';
                    String[] substrings = temp.Split(delimiter);
                    foreach (var substring in substrings)
                        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",substring,48));
                    if (temp == null) break;
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("end");
                        Console.ReadLine();
           }
                }

Answer (score 0):

This code breaks huge lines into separate
the data now need to write every 48 units of the array in one line with a fixed length of 48 elements of the array the regenal File Format is similar to csv

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string lin = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\New folder (7)\flltest.txt";
        using (StreamReader fs = new StreamReader(lin, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1255")))

            while (true)
            {
                string temp = fs.ReadLine();
                Char delimiter = ',';
                String[] substrings = temp.Split(delimiter);
                foreach (var substring in substrings)
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",substring,48));
                if (temp == null) break;
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("end");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }

            }
    }
```